# How can I replace values in an array of variables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
newRow =  "<tr><td>[[var1]]</td><td>[[var2]]</td><td>[[var3]]</td></tr>"
```

Now i have this array

```
data['var1'] ='test1';
data['var2'] ='test2';
data['var3'] ='test3';
```

I want to replace the above data in newRow in simplest possible way. How can I do that?

Comment: its a bit unclear, can you provide more details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do templating. Try [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)

Comment: You might want to read [this post](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(key, item) {
    newRow = newRow.replace('[[' + key + ']]', item);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H7MXH/)

Comment: thank sbuddy , that was good. One thing more , will it work if i have multiple instances of [[var1]] in the same variable. i think it will stop after replacing the first one

Comment: then change it to regex with /g modifier

Answer (score 5):

No need for jQuery:

```
newRow = newRow.replace(/\[\[(\w+)\]\]/g, function($0, $1) {
  return ($1 in data ? data[$1] : '');
  // empty string as fallback, if not available in data
});
```